Determining if a multimeter will damage ICs - How to confirm?
I’m looking for a straightforward way to determine if a particular multimeter will damage sensitive electronics such as ICs.
Specifically, let’s say I have a Fluke 117 multimeter and I am trying to take resistance measurements. If I have an ADS1278 that’s using, let’s say, a 1.8 V reference, can I determine if placing my probes from that reference point on the IC to GND will cause damage to the part (resistance measurement only, no power to circuit)? I have heard that this is possible, but do not see any literature online regarding the issue.
My initial thought is to take the open circuit test voltage from the Fluke datasheet and then determine the impedance of the reference point to GND from the ADS1278 datasheet.
Pulling from the above resources I have:
Voc = <2.7 V for the multimeter
Zref = 650 Ω worst case mode
The worst-case current that the reference port would be exposed to is 2.7 V/650 Ω = 4 mA
I do not see a reference port current limit in the datasheet to know if this current is acceptable.
My two questions are:

Is my methodology correct in determining the current that the ref port will see?
What parameter in the datasheet do I compare my 4 mA calculation to (assuming it's correct)?

Any and all help is appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Have a look at chapter 5.1 "input current", absolute maximum limit is +/- 10 mA.
